# Concatenate two instructions in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, makefile, terminal

I would like to make program with option -j after checking how many cores cpu has got.

```
#!/bin/bash
x="grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo"
make -j${x}
```

x variable display number of cores. make -j${x} not working

Comment: `make -j$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to capture the output of the command into a string through a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
make -j"${x}"
```